# Remove the first 1 and space before a phone number?

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, eregi

I did searches and figured this would be an easy find.  Though I haven't found anything related to exactly what I need and similar questions are from people from overseas that have different phone formats with plus signs.  A lot of my phone number entries start with a 1 and a space. I did a simple str_replace then I realized if a number has a 1 in the middle followed by a space, then that would mess it up

```
$string = trim($string);

$string = str_replace('1 ', '', $string);
```

That works for phone numbers beginning with

> 1 800-555-1111

> 1 222-555-1111

But in the case the phone number is

> 1 222 551 1111

Then that 551 and space would mess things up.  How can it be rewitten so that only the first 1 and the following space is removed and the rest is untouched?  Thanks.

EDIT

I forgot to mention that the entries do not always start with a 1 and a space.  Sometimes they may be

> 888-555-1111

> 888 555 1111

> 1 888 555 1111

Comment: Maybe it would be best to use a regex

Comment: Thanks but someone could pay me a million dollars and hold a gun to my head and give me 10 years to figure out regex/preg type stuff and I would never figure it out.  Even the tutorials give the bare basics and never explain the difficult parts that a human can understand.

Comment: @I_hate_arrays42 I have updated in the answer, try that

Comment: Are you looking for this? `^1\h+` https://regex101.com/r/lTlD8A/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **regex** to achieve this:-

```
$phone_number = '1 800-555-1111'
echo preg_replace('/^\d\s+/', '', $phone_number);
// Will echo 800-555-1111

$phone_number = '1 800 555 1111'
echo preg_replace('/^\d\s+/', '', $phone_number);
// Will echo 800 555 1111
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your code first and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could match 1 followed by one (or more) horizontal whitespace characters, and assert that there is a digit following.

```
^1\h+(?=\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhEqvO/1)

Or assert least 10 digits to the right where there can be an optional character other than a digit or a newline in between.

```
^1\h+(?=\d(?:[^\d\n\r]?\d){9}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2LHwz/1) } [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/9CLTf)

```
$strings = [
    "1 800-555-1111",
    "1 222-555-1111",
    "888-555-1111",
    "1 888 555 1111",
    "1 ",
    "1 2"
];

$pattern = '/^1\h+(?=\d(?:[^\d\n\r]?\d){9}$)/';

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $s) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
800-555-1111
222-555-1111
888-555-1111
888 555 1111
1 
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To `remove the first 1 and space`

`substr($string,2)`(without using the `trim()` method) or `substr($string,1)`(if you used the `trim()` method first) will work but are you sure that your number will always start with a `1` and `whitespace`?

Do you have any checks or conditions added to make sure that the user input will always start with a `1` and followed by a `space`?

If you are sure about that, then the substring solution removes those first two and then returns the rest of the string.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that is part of the problem.  It doesn't always start with a 1 and a space which is why I didn't use substr(). Sometimes the number could be 888-555-1111

Comment: I don't think that was your main issue though because even the answer you accepted does not deal with a situation where someone provides a number like this `1800 555 1111` for example. The `1` will still be there because the regex is looking for a `1` that's followed by a `whitespace`:
But I'm glad if it seems to work out for you.